# Javascript var is not loading in to facebook post to feed

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Every time I try to add my var of record it will not run the postToFeed function been trying to figure this out for a few days no any help would be great!

```
 <div id='fb-root'></div>
    <script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
    <p><a onclick='postToFeed(); return false;'>Post to Feed</a></p>
    <p id='msg'></p>

    <script> 
      FB.init({appId: "XXXXXXXXXXXX", status: true, cookie: true});

      function postToFeed() {

        // calling the API ...
        var obj = {
          method: 'feed',
          link: 'https://google.com',
          picture: 'http://google.com/logo.png',
          name: 'gamehighscore',
          caption: 'I just got a highscore of'+record+'',
          description: 'Try to beat my score!.'
        };

        function callback(response) {
          document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
        }

        FB.ui(obj, callback);
      }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, where is:

FB.init({appId: "XXXXXXXXXXXX", status: true, cookie: true});

FB javascript API has not been loaded. You need to load javascript API in this way:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true
    });
```

Or this way:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=XXXXXXXX";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Comment: The script works fine when i add variable  record it fails I hadd the app IP there i just XXXXXX for posting.

Comment: which script not work? Are you sure you write right values in [app's panel](https://developers.facebook.com/apps)